# Psycopg2 won't decode unicode characters

Tags: python, database, postgresql, unicode, psycopg2

I want to fetch and print a line from a PostgreSQL database in utf-8. The fetched line is the string "Produção". Although, when I print it, it prints "u'Produ\xe7\xe3o".

I already imported the following:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)
```

And still won't work. Using the decode() function won't work either. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Compare `s = u"Produção"; s` with `s = u"Produção"; print(s)`. The string is likely fine; you are simply getting a representation of the `unicode` object, rather than displaying it.

Comment: With `s=u"Produção"`it works fine. The thing is I have the "Produção" string stored in the variable `event`. So, how do I give the prefix u to that variable?

Comment: I got it! I just have to do `event.decode('unicode-escape')` and it works.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How are you actually retreiving the string? The `u'Produ\xe7\xe3o` indicates you already have a `unicode` object, which means it contains a literal UTF-8 encoded string. It's possible that the original string was encoded twice.